# Fitting data into a map in R

Tags: r, maps

First of all i'd like to apologize for my poor english. I'm trying to fit my data into Brazil's map and this is what i got:

[image]

Notice that my data goes from -0.53 to 0.73 and these values have the darkest colours in the plot. I want a legend that goes from -1 to 1 while having my outliers (-0.53/0.73) with lighter colours in the map and -1.0/1.0 with the darkest colours in the legend. Moreover i'd like the negative values to be red and the positive ones to be blue. How can i do that?

This is the code i'm currently using:

```
# Packages

library(maptools)
library(descr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plotrix)

# Reading shape files

estados <- readShapePoly(fn = 'estados_2010.shp')
estados2 <- readShapePoly(fn = 'estados_2010.shp') 

# Adding an order vector in the data frame

estados@data$order <- 1:nrow(estados@data) 

# Data to fit in the map

teste <- c(0.567072774466371,
           -0.144934811865636,
           0.595967865326944,
           0.479904421295722,
           0.251495518688696,
           0.195815073242536,
           0.548223329774688,
           0.463845521774005,
           0.272145251828454,
           0.580334048486482,
           0.649672015127772,
           0.584054575484519,
           0.671373957229477,
           0.436391947145788,
           0.522605768431274,
           0.641067907529059,
           0.570339843565797,
           0.381297082036819,
           0.474587396032187,
           0.462810571821925,
           0.558684078070584,
           -0.197881941278306,
           0.720551728476599,
           0.489189630257170,
           -0.538560893510226,
           0.732280520987057,
           0.555364159479124)

# Adding the data vector in the data frame

estados@data$dados <- teste

# Colours

myPaletteBlue <- brewer.pal(9,'RdBu')
createColors  <- colorRampPalette(myPaletteBlue, bias=3.3)
myColorsBlue  <- createColors(nrow(estados@data))

# Counting the number of colours

numberColors <- length(unique(myColorsBlue))

cuts <- quantile(estados@data$dados,
                 probs=(0:numberColors)/numberColors)

estados@data$dados2 <- cut(estados@data$dados,breaks = cuts,
                           include.lowest=T)

# Merging the data

colorOfdados2 <- data.frame(dados2=levels(estados@data$dados2),
                            colors=unique(myColorsBlue))
estados@data <- merge(estados@data, colorOfdados2)


# Ordering the data frame back to the first order

estados@data <- estados@data[order(estados@data$order),]

# Plot

plot(estados, col=as.character(estados@data$colors),
     lty=0)

plot(estados2, add=T) # Destaca as linhas dos estados no mapa

# Legend

color.legend(xl=-70, xr=-60,yb=-25,yt=-26, 
             legend=c('-0.53','','0.73'), 
             rect.col=myColorsBlue, gradient='x',
             cex=.8, pos=c(1,1,1))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I've noticed you've not got put the `library(package)` on the top of your code. If you are using other packages' functions, you ought to point them out.

Comment: `estados <- readShapePoly(fn = 'estados_2010.shp')` gives me errors, are you sure it's correct? `Error in getinfo.shape(filen) : Error opening SHP file`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply nhl. I forgot to mention that you need to read the file from your working directory. You can download the "estados_2010.shp" in this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B64xLcn8DZfwNF81dU5lQVdpTTQ/view